# Why it is trying to insert NULL in primary key property id.. MVC5 EF6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Entity Framework 6 Code First MVC5.Here is my class:

**Offer.cs**

```
 public class Offer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ListOffer { get; set; }
    }
```

**Here is my controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OfferFormViewModel viewModel)
{
        var offer = new Offer
        {
            ListOffer = viewModel.ListOffer,
        };
            _context.Offers.Add(offer);
            _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("MyOffers", "Offers");
     }
```

**OfferFormViewModel.cs**

```
public class OfferFormViewModel {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string ListOffer { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to insert a record in offers table, it works fine on my machine and inserts record in the database and it automatically assigns value to id column. But when I deploy the application  it throws the exception

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'DefaultConnection.dbo.Offers'; column does
>   not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.**

My question is why is it trying to insert NULL in Id column when I deploy the application and not when I run the code without deployment?

Comment: The problem is most probably on the database side. The Id should be an autoincrement field (in SQL Server it should be Identity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I deployed the application I copied the database to the server. On the server the Id column was not set to primary key and it was not an identity column either. I think something went wrong while copying the database to the server. That's why it was throwing the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Use this Model and  also update database with migration u can do this by following steps:

1. Open **Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console**.
2. enter`enable-migrations` in the **Package Manager Console**
3. enter`add-migration {name}`(make sure your application can built without any error).
4. enter`update-database`.

   ```
   public class Offer
   {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int Id { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string ListOffer { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You should use auto-increment, using Data Annotation:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public int Id { get; set; }
```

or FluentAPI

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Offers>()
        .Property(c => c.Id)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Comment: I think we do not need to use DatabaseGenerated attribute for a property named Id.